# yoga/yoga.h file not found RCTConvert.h

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, yoga-x1

I keep getting this error message whenever I do a pod install. I put 'use frameworks' and then this error pops up. When i remove the pod install my app is able to load. Can someone please assist me with what is wrong?

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

1. First thing if you are using pods in your project you should open  ios/Project_Name.xcworkspace instead of ios/Project_Name.xcodeproj in Xcode
2. If you get an error even did the above just try to add the following into your pod file

   pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

and run "pod install"

Comment: well i think in terms of context u do it!

Comment: when did you get this error message ? While debugging or Building app in release mode ?

Comment: I am getting this error using RN0.62.2 / Xcode 11.3. I have the specified yoga pod in my podfile. Any idea what I can do?

Comment: @Yossi where you able to make it work?

Comment: I was, but long time passed and I don't remember how I did it. Sorry...