# RCTConvert.h: 'yoga/Yoga.h' file not found

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, react-native-ios, yoga-x1

Same problem as in [yoga/yoga.h file not found RCTConvert.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53678999/yoga-yoga-h-file-not-found-rctconvert-h) but the answer there doesn't help.

I am using Xcode 11.3 on macOS Catalina (10.15.4), react-native 0.62.2, and getting this error when I try to build.

Any idea what I should do?

#### The import statement in RCTConvert.h:

```
#import <yoga/Yoga.h>
```

#### Files' locations

```
 ./node_modules/react-native/React/Base/RCTConvert.h
 ./node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/Yoga.h
```

#### Build settings -> Header Search Path

As you can see below, I tried to add the yoga directory. Didn't help.

[image: Build settings -> Header Search Path]

#### This is my podfile:

```
platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'xxx' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'

  pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
  pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
  pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
  pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
  pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'

  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'ReactCommon/callinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"

  pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  # Pods for xxx
  pod 'RNSquareInAppPayments', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-square-in-app-payments'
  pod 'BVLinearGradient', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient'
  pod 'react-native-nfc-manager', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-nfc-manager'

  target 'xxxTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

target 'xxx-tvOS' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for xxx-tvOS

  target 'xxx-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Embarrassingly, I don't remember... I had some many problems and solved this somehow. I will post an answer which contains the podfile that I am using now, that is working.

Comment: Thank you! For other folks encountering this issue in the future, I resolved it by updated cocoapods to the latest version.

Comment: I suggest that you post an answer

Answer (score 1):

I ended with the following podfile, which is working:

```
platform :ios, '11.1'
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

target 'xxx' do
  # Pods for xxx
  config = use_native_modules!
  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])

  pod 'react-native-netinfo', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/netinfo'

  pod 'RNCAsyncStorage', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage'

  pod 'react-native-restart', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-restart'

  pod 'react-native-blur', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/blur'

  pod 'RNSentry', :path => '../node_modules/@sentry/react-native'

  pod 'react-native-version-info', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-version-info'

  pod 'react-native-splash-screen', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-splash-screen'

  target 'xxxTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  use_flipper!
  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
  end
end

target 'xxx-tvOS' do
  # Pods for xxx-tvOS

  target 'xxx-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was able to resolve this problem by updating to the latest version of cocoapods (from 1.5.0 to 1.10.0).

You can check which version of cocoapods you have installed with this command: `gem which cocoapods`